# Unable to create Multiple shop with different templates in opencart

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

Firstly, thanks to all in advance for helping me,

I am Using opencart 1.5.3.1.And i Created multiple shop but i need multiple shops with different templates and layout.I try to change templates of each and every shop but unable to change.If i change theme of default templates of main shop then themes of all shop is changed.if i change the theme of other shop then there is no change...how can i solve this problem.Plz help me.

There is another problem is link of the shop.Link of all shops goes to the default shop.....
How can i solve this problem..

Plz help

Thanks to all once again.....

Answer (score 0):

I got solution of my question:

Solution is just change url of table store.....

Thanks