# multi shop templates opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

i'm using opencart v. 1.5.4.1, i have a subdomain like xx.domain.de with the same domain root as wwww.domain.de. The new store doesn't work as expected. I can't assign different themes to it, and all links are heading to the main store. Someone had that question before [Unable to create Multiple shop with different templates in opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099219/unable-to-create-multiple-shop-with-different-templates-in-opencart/12895928#12895928)
Thank you!

Comment: If You have a .htaccess file in your root, please paste it's contents here.

Comment: @JevgeniBogatyrjov Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.inter-grosshandel.de? [R=301,L]

Comment: dont get the right formatting here, sorry

Comment: I found the solution. Just a missing / at the end of the Domain of the store URL.